# Plotting distribution of variances

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution, probability-density, violin-plot

My dataset has 2 fields:

1. Time stamp t --- Varies between 0 to 60
2. Variable x – variance in value of a variable (say, A) from t-1 to t. Varies between -100%  to 100%

There are roughly 500 records for each value of time stamp- e.g.
500 records where t= 0 and x takes any value between -100% to 100% 
490 records where t= 1 and x takes any value between -100% to 100%, and so on.
Note, the value of x is 0 for ~80% of the records

The aim here is to determine at what value of t (Can be one value, or a range, e.g., when t= 22, or is between 20 -25), is the day-on-day change in A the minimum: Which effectively translates to finding out t when x is very frequently= 0, and when not, is at least close to zero. 
To this purpose, I aim to plot the variance of x for each day. I can think of using a violin plot with x (Y axis) and t (X-axis), but there being 60 values of t makes it difficult to plot all in one chart. 
Can you suggest any alternative plot for the intended visual analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you do the absolute value of the variance (so its concentrated in 0-100) and trying with logs in here? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251066/boxplot-for-data-with-a-large-number-of-zero-values.

When you say smallest, you mean closest to 0, right? In this case its better to work to reduce absolute variance (on a 0-1 scale), as you can then treat this like zero-inflated binomial data e.g. with the VGAM package: https://rdrr.io/cran/VGAM/man/zibinomial.html

I've had a play around, and below is an example that I think makes sense. I've only had some experience with zero-inflated models, so would be good if anyone has some feedback :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(VGAM)

# simulate some data
N_t <- 60 # number of t
N_o <- 500 # number of observations at t
t_smallest <- 30 # best value
# simulate some data crudely
set.seed(1)
dataL <- lapply(1:N_t, function(t){
  
  dist <- abs(t_smallest-t)+10
  values <- round(rbeta(N_o, 10/dist, 300/dist), 2) * sample(c(-1,1), N_o, replace=TRUE)
  data.table(t, values)
})
data <- rbindlist(dataL)
# raw
ggplot(data, aes(factor(t), values)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 0.1))
# log transformed - may look better with your data
ggplot(data, aes(factor(t), log(abs(values)+1))) + 
  geom_violin()

# use absolute values, package needs it as integer p & n, so approximate these
data[, abs.values := abs(values)]
data[, p := round(1000*abs.values, 0)]
data[, n := 1000]
# with a gam, so smooth fit on t. Found it to be unstable though
fit <- vgam(cbind(p, n-p) ~ s(t), zibinomialff, data = data, trace = TRUE)
# glm, with a coefficient for each t, so treats independently
fit2 <- vglm(cbind(p, n-p) ~ factor(t), zibinomialff, data = data, trace = TRUE)

# predict
output <- data.table(t=1:N_t)
output[, prediction := predict(fit, newdata=output, type="response")]
output[, prediction2 := predict(fit2, newdata=output, type="response")]

# plot out with predictions
ggplot(data, aes(factor(t), abs.values)) + 
  geom_boxplot(col="darkgrey") + 
  geom_line(data=output, aes(x=t, y=prediction2)) + 
  geom_line(data=output, aes(x=t, y=prediction), col="darkorange") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = output[prediction==min(prediction), t]) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 0.1))
```

Comment: Many thanks. Alternatively, what if I considered a variance of +/- 2% was acceptable, & converted x into a binary variable based on this condition? Then find the probability of x=0 (success) for each t, given the data (i.e., from the 500 records of x for each t)? Would you know how to work that out in R?

Comment: To explain, how do I determine the probability density function of x=success (i.e. |x| < .02) for each value of t, basis which I can compute the probability of the true probability of getting |x| < .02 being between say, 0.9 and 1?